Getting the unique ID number of a record in react
I am trying to send data from one table in my database to another. In my frontend, I have a table that displays the details of the records/data of the table that I am trying to copy from. On each record, I have the approve button which when pressed, sends the row data of one record to the other table. I am getting an error in which all the records are being sent to the other database and it continues to loop.
Here is my frontend code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import '../css/Approve_user.css';

function Approve_user() {

    const [pendinguser, setPendinguser] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=> {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5500/getpendingdata')
        .then(res=>setPendinguser(res.data))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }, [])

    const handleApprove = (i) => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:5500/approveduser', i)
        .then(res => {
            if(res.data.Status === 'Success'){
                alert("User Approved Successfully!");
                window.location.reload()
            }
            else{
                alert(res.data.Error);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    return(
        <section className="Approve_users">
            <div className="Approve_title">
                <h3>Approve New Users Section</h3>
                <h5>Select and Decline Users</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="pendingusers">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Ticket ID</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Phone No.</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Skill</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            pendinguser.map((data, i) => (
                                <tr key={i}>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_ID}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_firstname}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_lastname}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_username}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_gender}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_location}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_phone_no}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_email}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_category}</td>
                                    <td>{data.pending_user_skill}</td>
                                    <td className="buttons">
                                        <button className='Approve' onClick={handleApprove(i)}>Approve</button>
                                        <button className='Delete'>Delete</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            ))
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default Approve_user;

And here is my backend code:
app.post('/approveduser', (req, res) => {
    const sql = "INSERT INTO users(`user_firstname`, `user_lastname`, `user_username`, `user_gender`, `user_location`, `user_phone_no`, `user_email`, `user_password`, `user_category`, `user_profilepic`, `user_skill`) SELECT `pending_user_firstname`, `pending_user_lastname`, `pending_user_username`, `pending_user_gender`, `pending_user_location`, `pending_user_phone_no`, `pending_user_email`, `pending_user_password`, `pending_user_category`, `pending_user_profilepic`, `pending_user_skill` FROM pending_users WHERE pending_user_ID=?";

    const approve_ID = req.body.i;

    db.query(sql, [approve_ID], (err, result) => {
        if(err) return res.json({Error: err});
        else return res.json({Status: "Success"}); 
    })
})

Let's say the table data is for records, So am expecting to have two submit buttons for each record. So when I press the approve button for record A, am expecting record A to be copied from the pending_users table to the users table and the same if I press the approve button for record B.

So you need onClick={() => handleApprove(i)} to prevent it calling on render

You need to update this piece of code, right now the function is triggered every time the page re-renders and not on the button click you wanted.
 <button className='Approve' onClick={handleApprove(i)}>Approve</button>

DO THIS INSTEAD
 <button className='Approve' onClick={() =>handleApprove(i)}>Approve</button>


The reason your function is executing during rendering is because you are running the function during onClick instead of registering it. There are two ways in which you could overcome this issue.
Method 1
<button className='Approve' onClick=>{handleApprove}>Approve</button>


This passes your function to onClick binding instead of calling it. Onclick's event will be passed to your function parameter in this case.

Opt for this method if you dont need any extra parameters passed to your function other than the onClick event.


Method 2
<button className='Approve' onClick={() => handleApprove(i)}>Approve</button>


This type invokes an arrow function whenever onClick is triggered and your function is called inside that. This could be an option when you need additional parameters to be passed instead of the onClick event.

You would have to go with this method to manually pass the index to your function.




I am getting an error in which all the records are being sent to the other database and it continues to loop.

The present code flows as below:
a. The component is being loaded initially.
b. The state pendinguser is initialised to an empty array.
c. Therefore there is nothing to render by the statement pendinguser.map...
d. The component completes its mounting.
e. Upon mounting, the useEffect comes into work.
f. It fetches the data via the API call.
g. And the state is changed with the data fetched.
h. The state change triggers a new render.
i. During this render, it executes the handler handleApprove for each record it renders.
j. The first invocation of the handler calls the API, and transfer the first record successfully.
k. Soon after the API completes, the statement window.location.reload() reloads the component which resets the state pendinguser to an empty array.
l. The component completes its mounting or it is remounted.
m. This causes the useEffect to work again.
n. It fetches the remaining data, and the rest is a repetition of the steps from the step g onwards.
The process will repeat indefinite.
Please note that during this indefinite action, the transfer will be complete. The whole data would be transferred from the source to the target.
Now even after the whole data has been transferred, the app continues. It does so because of the statement window.location.reload() which gets executed after the last row has been transferred successfully. This particular reload will remount the component, which will again cause the useEffect to work. Though there is no data returned by this time, and therefore there is no state change to happen, the status 'SUCCESS' returned from the API will cause another reload to execute. This will be continued indefinite.
The solution proposed
a. Do not invoke the function handleApprove, instead just pass the function as such. This has been already given in other answers as well. The same code has copied below.
<button className='Approve' onClick={() => handleApprove(i)}>Approve</button>

b. Do not reload the window which may be unsuitable for Single Page Applications in general.

"This has been already given in other answers as well"... so why repeat it in yet another answer? Also, you're missing the i parameter

Hi @Phil, There are two issues in the original code. The other answers have covered the first issue. The second issue in using the statement window.location.reload() is included in this post only. This statement is the reason the app goes indefinite. And thank you a lot to spot the missing, I have corrected the code.
